# any free asp.net based spell checker for asp:textbox

Tags: asp.net

does anyone know about any control/library for asp.net based application's textbox spell checking....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a JavaScript spell checker (like [Speller Pages](http://spellerpages.sourceforge.net/)) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try NetSpell http://sourceforge.net/projects/netspell. It's a widely used and well written free Spell Checker for .NET framework. You'll have to wire it to your textboxes, but that shouldn't be that hard to do. It hasn't been updated in quite a while, but it's still used by a lot of projects out there. Alternatively try NHunspell http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/. Never worked with it myself, but it looks like a nice solution.